Selecting field values that are integers or decimals with QGIS expression
I am trying to select features using an expression in a single file. The file contains polylines (contours) set at an elevation.
I want to select all features that are decimal: 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, etc. Then I will delete them to be left only with values that are integers: 1, 2, 3, etc. The field type is Decimal Double.
I'm doing this to create two separate files for major and minor contours from my single file. I have tried to do this by exporting as CSV and filtering manually in Excel but in the end, some contour lines are missing and I am not sure why.

You can use modulo:
"myfield" % 1 <> 0

Which means: Select rows where the remainder of "myfield" divided by 1 is not 0.

